# what does "first four" mean?

Tags: word-usage

Jack and Annie's *first four* missions as Master Librarians are to save stories from ancient libraries.

what does "first four" mean? is "first four" the same meaning as "one out of four"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider six missions which we label m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6. The **first four** of these are m1, m2, m3, and m4.

You are told to give $1 to each of the **first three** people you meet next day. You meet Jack, Mary, Peter, and Kwame in that order. Jack, Mary, and Peter get the money. Kwame does not.

You work in a café. The manager says 'Stand by the door and give the **first four** people who come in a voucher for a free cup of coffee'. You stand by the door, and the first person who comes in gets a voucher, then the second, then the third, then the fourth. Now you have no more vouchers.